# What is the sql equivalent of hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I need to use the following query but i am not able to use spring injection so i need to make the query in simple sql.

How can i make the command that don't uses sessionfactory and any other beans

where registration is my entity class with username and password

```
public Registration findUserByEmail(String email) {

     try {

          Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          String query = "FROM Registration WHERE email =:email";
          Query query2 = session.createSQLQuery(query); 
          query2.setString("email",email);
          return (Registration) query2.uniqueResult();

     } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                throw new RuntimeException("DAO failed", e);
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no need to make sql query since you have an entity. Hibernate is not dependent on Spring to get the SessionFactory so you don't have to think about "**beans**" 
Depending on your configuration (I assume its annotation based), you can create a session factory like -

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                                        .configure("classpath/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                        .buildSessionFactory();
```

and if it is not annotation based then you can use

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

[this link may help.](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/245.html)

As a side note - if you're still willing to fire sql (will not recommend though) then do it in plain JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

There's no Spring-specific code in your example. `SessionFactory` is a Hibernate interface and you will need Hibernate for mapping your entity to/from the database. The SQL query executed by Hibernate will be something like

```
select * from registration where email = 'email'
```

with `*` being the mapped columns and the email as given in the parameter.

If you really require to get rid of Hibernate, including all mapping logic and session handling, you could build the mapping yourself [using plain JDBC](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity#Examples) for issuing the SQL query and mapping the `ResultSet` to a `new Registration()` yourself. Of course, this is a lot more cumbersome than using an ORM like Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
```

in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`

It prints every query executed by it on the console.